# Help identifying file type

Tags: file-types

I've got a file that's got internet sites visited, I want to know what's the program that generates this file.

The file's lines look as the following.

```
11/28/2010 09:14:19    842 10.0.0.224 TCP_MISS/302 701 POST http://secure.logmein.com/versioncheck.asp - DIRECT/69.25.20.193 text/html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could be a Squid log file - [An example](http://www.mail-archive.com/squid-users@squid-cache.org/msg50354.html).

Comment: Where can I find documentation about the meaning of each field.?

Comment: http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.0/cfgman/logformat.html has the fields (I believe you are configured with the first log string `squid`).  http://www.tenon.com/support/webten/papers/squidlog.shtml is also a nice overview of the logging.